# Is there a resource overview for systems?

Tags: stellaris

When playing for the first time today I noticed that I have to tediously click on every planet to see its resources and other information.

**Q**: Is there an overview of some kind listing all that information, e.g. on a per-system-basis?

Answer (score 2):

Found it in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/4ix8nq/strategic_resource_where_to_view/) Reddit post.

> When you are in the Galaxy Map press ALT and it will show the resources of the star systems you have surveyed. You have to be zoomed in a bit for this to work, but it still allows the viewing of the resources of like 50 star systems.

EDIT: There is also a toggle to make this viewable all the time, in the bottom-right portion of the screen (by the Map Mode buttons). Thanks to @SableDreamer for pointing this out.

Comment: There is also a toggle to make this viewable all the time, in the bottom-right portion of the screen (by the Map Mode buttons).